# In Ruby, how do you set an alias to an object you get from a constant like `ENV`?

Tags: ruby, singleton, alias

Given that `ENV` is neither a class nor a module, it is not possible to directly alias one of its singleton methods with the following usual mechanism:

```rb
class SomeClass
  class << self
    alias some_alias some_existing_method
  end
end
```

Is there nonetheless a way to alias a method like `ENV::[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, the trick is to evaluate the alias statement within the context of the singleton class:

```
  ENV.singleton_class.class_eval do
      alias jet []
  end
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this though. If you want to provide a different interface for core objects its better to use delegation to create a wrapper. Monkeying with core objects has a tendency to blow up in your face.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @max. I’m doing it in the frame of [Englishest](https://github.com/psychoslave/englishest), a ruby gem I develop to deepen my knowledge of the Ruby language and allow me to code with it with less ideograms when I want to do so. Feel free to have a look and send me feedback by opening an issue there.